# A couple of random questions about quantum stuff

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, navier-stokes

I learned a few years ago how fluids and solids behave in a classical way. Also how some thermodynamic properties of solids arise from electrons in condensed matter (Bloch thing and etc), and the same with gasses in quantum statistical mechanics.

Is there a quantum version of Navier-Stokes equation? What quantum theory says about approximate incomprehensibility of fluids? An explanation of viscosity?
Edit: I deleted the unrelated question. Also, I know we can get good predictions by knowing that classical mechanics is an approximation to QM, but I think that it's interesting enough this question to be asked anyway. I mean, this has to have been done somewhere, I want to know how it's called and how they have done that. Justifying material derivative and all that stuff in QM can be really weird (I think), but it's interesting for it's own sake (I think).

Comment: Hello! It would be better to only ask one question per post, otherwise it might get closed due to lack of focus. You can [edit] your question or [ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new one. Thanks!

Comment: In general I think it's better to prove to yourself that chemistry or thermodynamics follow from QM and then use those to make predictions about large systems than to try to apply QM to them directly.

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, the Navier-Stokes equations are a set of partial differential equations arising from certain conservation laws such as the conservation of momentum and mass for a portion of fluid and in general one also has to define a constitutive equation which is a (in general, a differential) equation between the Cauchy's stress tensor and the strain tensor. Finally, they are coupled in order to form a closed set of equations that can be solved.

The underlying assumption which allows to write these equations is that the matter is a continuum and therefore, in a representative point of a portion of fluid, there is a number of particles equivalent to the Avogadro number.

Hence, it is a big risk, in my opinion, to find a strict connection with the quantum formalism!

Nevertheless, there is a wonderful formalism introduced by Madelung which formally recasts the Schrödinger equation into a Navier-Stokes-like equation.

See for instance:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_hydrodynamics

Such a formalism is intriguing because allows to describe quantum system which manifests a fluid behavior as for instance superfluid helium.

Comment: I knew about the Madelung equation, I don't consider it interesting. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: (Also, I know what's Navier-Stokes equation...)

Comment: You are wondering if there exists a quantum version of Navier-Stokes equation but you do not consider interesting the Madelung equation......

Comment: (Probably, you do not what is Navier-Stokes equation then...)
Thanks anyway for posing your interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for insulting me! Maybe when I studied fluid mechanics at college I didn't study that, because I don't know what is Navier-Stokes...
Madelung equation is trying to make quantum mechanics with fluid mechanics, not what I asked...
Well, maybe a reference on quantum hydrodynamics could be useful.

Comment: I am not insulting anybody! 
To the contrary, I just think it is impolite to answer in that way to someone (the only one) that was trying to share his opinion/knowledge. 
Before answering to your question, I was reflecting about the connection between them and the Madelung equation is based on a formalism (equivalent to the Schrödinger equation) which describes quantum object and it does not "make quantum mechanics with fluid mechanics". The interesting thing is that it describes quantum systems which show a collective behavior like a fluid. Here, there is a connection with Navier-Stokes!

Comment: Sorry for being impolite. Surely Madelung equation is interesting for many people, but it's not what I tried to ask about to. My native language isn't english and maybe I didn't explained well what I was asking about. Definitely your answer is a great answer for another question (and maybe to the question that I wrote, not the question that I intended to write).